# Session-timeout not working when used with cookie-config

Tags: servlet-3.0

I am using servlet 3.0 pointing it properly in web.xml.

```
     <session-config>
          <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
          <cookie-config>
                  <http-only>true</http-only>
                  <secure>true</secure>
          </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

The application gets deployed but when I hit the URL I get error saying session timeout.

When I remove cookie-config and only put session-timeout it works just fine, the session stays for an hour even when user is inactive.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you show your web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

After lot of analysis, the mistake was trivial.

The problem was the URL which I was using was http:// but should have been https://

Answering the question as it may be helpful to someone.